# querying for the existing of a specific set of records in the database

Tags: sqlite

I'm storing various sequences in an SQLite database.  Each sequence has its own sequence id, and each item in the sequence has its own index in the sequence as well as a value.

```
CREATE TABLE Sequence (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                       SequenceId INTEGER, 
                       Index INTEGER, 
                       Value TEXT);
```

As an example, the first sequence I might add could be "Red", "Green", "Blue" as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Sequence (SequenceId, Index, Value) VALUES (1,1,"Red"), (1,2,"Green"), (1,3,"Blue");
```

I get the SequenceId from another table. 
When I am ready to add a new sequence to the database I first want to make sure that it's not already there.  My first thought was that I could construct a query checking for the existing of each row in the sequence and AND them together.  For instance, before adding the sequence "Red", "Green", "Blue" I would run a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sequence 
           WHERE SequenceId = ? AND Index = 1 AND Value='Red')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sequence 
           WHERE SequenceId = ? AND Index = 2 AND Value='Green')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sequence 
           WHERE SequenceId = ? AND Index = 3 AND Value='Blue')
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sequence 
           WHERE SequenceId = ? AND Index = 4);
```

I don't care about what the actual SequenceId previously assigned was, only if the sequence exists.  But then I realized that I have no way of making sure that `SequenceId` is the same for each EXISTS clause.

Is there some way in SQLite of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by sequenceid` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select sequenceid
from sequence
group by sequenceid
having 
  sum(`index` = 1 and `value` = 'Red') > 0
  and 
  sum(`index` = 2 and `value` = 'Green') > 0
  and
  sum(`index` = 3 and `value` = 'Blue') > 0
```

This code will return one (or more) existing `sequenceid`s containing "Red", "Green" and "Blue".
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5NhDbVusup6NJaxATjL3h/0).
If you don't need the `sequenceid`s, use it as a subquery:

```
select exists (
  select sequenceid
  from sequence
  group by sequenceid
  having 
    sum(`index` = 1 and `value` = 'Red') > 0
    and 
    sum(`index` = 2 and `value` = 'Green') > 0
    and
    sum(`index` = 3 and `value` = 'Blue') > 0
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5NhDbVusup6NJaxATjL3h/1).
Or with a CTE:

```
with cte(`Index`, `Value`) as (
  select * from (
    values (1, 'Red'), (2, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue')
  )
)
select exists (
  select sequenceid
  from sequence
  where (`index`, `value`) in (select `index`, `value` from cte)
  group by sequenceid
  having count(*) = 3
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5NhDbVusup6NJaxATjL3h/2).